# Why don't we have a "List of proposed FAQ"?

Tags: discussion, support

We do have a list of FAQ:

> [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](/q/7931/)

Some time ago, when I wanted to learn a few about the association bonus and tag badges, I typed these into the search bar

```
[faq] association bonus
[faq] tag badge
```

Well, it yielded no result. I check the FAQ list but to no avail.

Soon I had an idea and again searched for:

```
[faq-proposed] tag badge
```

Sorting by votes, it's right the second one. Lol, hadn't thought it wasn't an FAQ.

If there were a list of proposed FAQs, it would've been good.

Should we have one?

Comment: Downvoter please post an answer?

Comment: What’s wrong with searching [[tag:faq-proposed]]?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft What's wrong with searching with [[meta-tag:faq]]?

Comment: Stack Exchange's search system is suboptimal. A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+faq+tag+badge) works better.

Comment: umm... same way we don't have list of [tag:support] questions? Or list of any other tag questions?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I mean [[tag:faq-proposed]]

Comment: I know. But it's just a tag, not special enough to deserve its own list. Once it becomes a faq, then it should be added to the faq list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then why [[meta-tag:faq]]?

Comment: Because those are special, and semi-official. Essentially what Patrick said now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is simply no need for such a list. The list of FAQ posts approved by a community manager *is* useful. It is the comprehensive guide to most asked questions.

The proposed FAQ list isn't anything more than a list maintained by the community of posts that can become a FAQ. You and I can edit a post with that tag, simply because we feel like it. Is there any use in maintaining a list of those posts? No. Just like there is no use in a separate list for bugs or feature requests. The tag search works well enough for these cases: [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).